# Clojure constantly and map function

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

Why does this bit of Clojure code:

```
user=> (map (constantly (println "Loop it.")) (range 0 3))
```

Yield this output:

```
Loop it.
(nil nil nil)
```

I'd expect it to print "Loop it" three times as a side effect of evaluating the function three times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`constantly` doesn't evaluate its argument multiple times. It's a function, not a macro, so the argument is evaluated exactly once before `constantly` runs. All `constantly` does is it takes its (evaluated) argument and returns a function that returns the given value every time it's called (without re-evaluating anything since, as I said, the argument is evaluated already before `constantly` even runs).

If all you want to do is to call `(println "Loop it")` for every element in the range, you should pass that in as the function to map instead of `constantly`. Note that you'll actually have to pass it in as a function, not an evaluated expression.

Comment: Glanced at the source. This looks like a winner.

Comment: Was trying to use constantly to avoid explicitly passing in an argument I don't need. Will settle for this, though.

Comment: Note that if you just want side-effects, you should use `doseq` or `dotimes`. Since `map` is lazy, you won't get the result you want unless you force it with `doall` or `dorun`.

Comment: @sepp2k Your description of `constantly` is wrong. You describe `repeat`. `constantly` returns a function which when called will return the value provided to `constantly`.

Comment: @kotarak Sorry about that. Fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a behavior close to your intent by usig [repeatedly](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/repeatedly) and a lambda expression.

For instance:

```
(repeatedly 3 #(println "Loop it"))
```

Unless you're at the REPL, this needs to be surrounded by a `dorun` or similar. `repeatedly` is lazy.

Comment: Lambda won't compile due to it wanting to use the argument I pass to it. In this case, I'd rather just ignore the argument.

Comment: I've added an example of use, analogous to yours.

Comment: Oh, that makes much more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As sepp2k rightly points out `constantly` is a function, so its argument will only be evaluated once.

The idiomatic way to achieve what you are doing here would be to use `doseq`:

```
(doseq [i (range 0 3)]
  (println "Loop it."))
```

Or alternatively `dotimes` (which is a little more concise and efficient in this particular case as you aren't actually using the sequence produced by `range`):

```
(dotimes [i 3]
  (println "Loop it."))
```

Both of these solutions are non-lazy, which is probably what you want if you are just running some code for the side effects.